# Find $\iint_D (1+xy)\,dA$ where $D=\{(x,y):1\leq x^2 +y^2\leq 2, y\geq0\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Let $D=\{(x,y):1\leq x^2 +y^2\leq 2, y\geq0\}$. Solve $\iint_D (1+xy)\,dA$.

I thought about bounding $x\in [-2,-1]\cup[1,2]$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq\sqrt{2-x^2}$ and then solve the double integral. Btw, before doing this, I checked wolfram alpha and it gives me a complex number. According to my book, the result is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Is my integral well-written?

Comment: Have you tried polar coordinates?

Comment: Nope, polar coordinates still don't appear. However, that might solve it more easily?

Comment: Yes, I think polar coordinates would be much easier. In any case, I think your bounds on $x$ are wrong: for instance, $(0,1)$ is a point in $D$, but the $x$-value doesn't lie in either of those intervals.

Comment: Oh, I see...I did something wrong, gonna re-do it later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the region $D$, $x$ can range anywhere from $-\sqrt{2} \;\;$ to $+\sqrt{2} \;\;.$ This means that the bounds for $x$ should reflect this. If we then restrict $y$ as you suggest then our integral becomes

$$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^\sqrt{2}\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} (1 + xy)\; dydx = \frac{\pi}{2} + bi\tag{1}$$ for some $b$ that I don't want to derive. The fact that $b\neq0$ is a problem that suggests that the setup is incorrect. Think carefully about what were asking this integral to do. We are trying to plug a value $x\in (-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ in to the region between a half circle of radius 1 and its concentric half circle of radius 2. As we get close to the inner circle for $|x|\gt 1 $ we run into complex numbers that don't belong in our "area" integral! This means we should break up the integral in a way that won't go out of the real, natural domain of the square root function. Consider what would happen if you integrated over the larger half circle and subtracted the integral over the smaller half circle. Observe that this idea gives

$$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} (1 + xy)\; dydx - \int_{-1}^1\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} (1 + xy)\; dydx \tag{2}$$

which is not quite equivalent $\textbf{(1)}.$ Intuition says however that this should be the right thing to do and in fact upon evaluation $\textbf{(2)}$ yields a result of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for this detailed answer, helped me a lot to understand :)

Comment: Why bother with integration at all? Obviously the $xy$ part yields $0$ because of parity, and the integral of $1$ is simply the area of a half-ring.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes that's a clever observation but it's important to understand how to set up the integral even if it is unnecessary in this case. My answer is for the sake of the OP and for the sake of those wanting to learn to set up double integrals on regions such as this.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, too.